# ASP.NET routing and physical paths in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization

I use ASP.NET routing to rename the full paths of my URLs (ie. /page1/page2/file.aspx would just become /file.aspx). This doesn't work with web.config authorization, because that uses physical path/folder names. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

See **Routing and Security** section:

[Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx#id0070044)

Comment: I've been battling this problem and the link to this article is great, but I've just found that I can open out anonymous access (`users="*"`) by applying a location path of the physical page rather than the routing url.  Could this have changed since 2009?